# Why spring always resolves <form:checkbox> to true?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

The issue is that spring 3 renders `<form:checkbox>` element as true. But `@Controller` set its value as false.

On jsp page it is :

```
<form:form id="hostelSearchForm" modelAttribute="hs" method="POST"
                cssClass="mainForm">
    <div class="checkbox">
                                <fmt:message key="family" var="family" />
                                <form:checkbox path="family" label="${family}" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <fmt:message key='children' var='children' />
                                <form:checkbox path="children" label="${children}" />
                            </div>
.......
<input id="hostelSearchFormButton" type="button" 
                            value="${searchButtonLabel}" />
</form:form>
```

Inside `@Controller` I forward to jsp newly created `modelAttribute` with all default values where booleans are false.

On jsp checkboxes are rendered as false. But their attrbiute `value` is `true`(I see on page source) and when I submit form I receive true for all checkboxes which I didn't check.

In my spring `@Controller` I decided to use `@InitBinder` to solve my issue:

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBooleanBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Boolean.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
            @Override
            public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                System.out.println("bind boolean property string " + text);
                super.setValue(text != null ? text.equals("on") : false);
            }

            @Override
            public void setValue(Object value) {
                System.out.println("bind boolean property " + value);
                if (value instanceof Boolean)
                    super.setValue((boolean) value ? "ON" : "OFF");
                else
                    super.setValue(value);
            }
        });
    }
```

But it is called only before rendering jsp page. Method `setValue` is called and values are false as expected. But when form is submitted these values are true and `@InitBinder` isn't called.

**EDIT**

Form is rendered by :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String search(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        logger.debug("Forwarding to hostel search page");

        CountryInfo countryInfo = restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=geonameUser2014", CountryInfo.class);
        List<Country> countries = countryInfo.getCountries();
        List<Gender> genders = Arrays.asList(Gender.values());

        model.addAttribute("countries", countries);
        model.addAttribute("genders", genders);
        model.addAttribute("hs", new HostelSearch());
        return "hostel/search";
    }
```

After this method runs, `<form:form>`(shown above) is rendered and checkboxes are as:

```
<input id="smoking1" name="smoking" type="checkbox" value="true"/><label for="smoking1">Smoking</label><input type="hidden" name="_smoking" value="on"/>
```

Values are already wrong. Form is initially rendered with wrong values! In bean `hs` I have false for `smoking` roperty but on jsp page it is true.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You do not give enough information so I have to guess. `<form:checkbox>` tag is translated by Spring in two tags : `<form:checkbox path="family" label="${family}" />` gives

```
<input name="family" type="checkbox" value="value_of_family_whatever_it_is"/>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="_family"/>
```

HTML `<input type=checkbox>` is not transmitted by browsers when not checked. That's the reason for the hidden tag.
If you use a *normal* submit button, all is fine, because Spring knows about the hidden tag and uses it to know which tags were present in render form and sets to false all checkboxes params for which it sees the hidden tag.

But as you say you use an ajax submit but do not tell how, you will now have to verify how the jsp is translated in HTML and what your javascript send to the controller.